# RCPP Armadillo: Print integer value in function

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

New to CPP and RCPP

I am putting together an R package with RCPP.

Here are my steps:

1. Transfer to directory with package.
2. Run compileAttributes(pkgdir = ".",verbose=TRUE)
3. Then run build and install from devtools.

I want one of my CPP functions to print a message whenever it is invoked.
So i added :

```
Rcpp::Rcout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

I then went through steps 1 to 3 above. But no cigar. Not even a cigarillo.

Ideally, I want it to print out an integer value i, somthing like

Sample code.

```
Rcpp::Rcout << i << std::endl;
```

SO far, it compiles and the function runs - but no printout of the dear variable. HELP! An example of my function is below. I suspect there is some standard way to either pass the values to R or to simply print from CPP.

```
    # include <RcppArmadillo.h>
    // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
    // [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

    using namespace Rcpp ;
    arma::mat sillyme (arma::mat FE) {
  
    arma::mat FEE = FE ;
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    Rcpp::Rcout << FE.n_rows << std::endl;

    return(FEE) ;
    }
```

Comment: Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. I would start with a standalone C++ file exporting the function with an `// [[Rcpp::export]]` attribute and reproduce the unwanted behavior in that way, then you have an easy minimum reproducible code to [edit] into your question for us to be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: Agreed, see update. I dont want to post a full project skeleton etc.

Comment: Maybe you should, or at least maybe you should look more closely at what the skeloton generates: in a package you do not need `Rcpp::depends()` or `Rcpp::plugins()` as this is dealt with at the `DESCRIPTION` file level (and maybe `src/Makevars`, but these days C++11 is already the default anyway).  All harmless --but *details matter*.

Comment: You've got an example here, but not reproducible; I demonstrate in an "answer" that this code works as you describe that you want it to. Have you tried this _exact_ code on your own machine? Did it compile fine? If so, how **exactly** did it behave when you called it from R?

Comment: Excellent points let me try an distill my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system (Ubuntu 20.04, R 4.0.0), this works just as expected (after adding a `// [[Rcpp::export]]` attribute to make sure the function is callable from R):

```r
sillyme(diag(2))
# Hello World!
# 2
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    0    1
```

Comment: Yes, the `[[Rcpp::export]]` matters in a package!  If it is missing you get a warning, and if you ignore those ... well then you may get disappointing results.